# my transaction is pending 3 days old ... what to do ? please help

Tags: blockchain

I have sent 0.278 bitcoins to someone from my blockchain website and my transaction is in pending now is 3 days passed ...I didn't know I have to pay any fees ....it is first time when I use blockchain website ,what's happens they steal my money ?
this is the transaction https://blockchain.info/address/1C5Crpv7UufcqR2mhHjVE2V2tXr2gfBSky

please someone can help me what to do to cancel the transaction and pay the fees ?or what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction says it has a fee of 120.32 sat/B.

Check out the following to get an idea of what fees you should pay: https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

As of this writing, it would cost around 300 satoshis/Byte to be probably processed within 30 minutes; and the fee you provided is estimated to take up to 1020 minutes (17 more hours) - with a 90% certainty.

What can happen:

- You supplement the transaction with some more miner fee (not sure how to do this using Blockchain's wallet).
- The transaction eventually makes it into a block, with its current fee
- The transaction "expires", as in, gets "forgotten" if enough miners clear their memory pool before it gets included in a block - highly unlikely.

*Edit*: The question is a duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)